# Trying to connect with Google API but not able to connect

Tags: java, liferay-7.4

I am trying to connect with google api using liferay 7.4 framework and java as well.
I have used this lines of code mentioned below:
LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(9080).build()
so i am getting an exception am not able get the value of receiver.

I had tried so many ports but still i am getting an exception.
I have created an account in google workspace and create the credentials.

I have taken a reference from this link:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent.

please resolve my query.

Thanks & Regards,
Anil Kumar Shrivastava